# Move file to another Git repository with history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have one repo. I need to move some files and directories to another repo.
I managed to extract directory using `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter config/deploy -- --all`.

I also need to move file `config/deploy.rb`.

How to do this?

Comment: If you are moving a file to a completely different repo, how can the history possibly go with it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The history in one repo can be copied to the other repo as a series of patches. They will retain Author dates.

Comment: The key here is that *files* don't really *have* history in Git. *Commits* have history—or more precisely, *are* the history. And, of course, commits have files. So it's quite the other way around: it's not that files have history, it's that history has files! In the end, then, when you want to copy or add some history from repo A to repo B, that means you want to copy *commits* from A to B. (As with `git filter-branch`, you may want to modify the commits in the copying process.)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the patches.

As commenter Tim implied, git history technically cannot be moved from one repo to another. However, since you're rewriting history anyway, you obviously want to copy the file's history into your new repo.

I have some scripts that do this and work fine with the following caveats:

- ***The files were never renamed.***
- Every execution creates new commits.

For brevity, I'm only listing the meat of the scripts:

```
# git-cp-history
OTHER_REPO_DIR="$1"
FILES="$@"
git-export-history "$FILES" | git-import-history "$OTHER_REPO_DIR"

# git-export-history
FIRST_COMMIT=`git log --format=%H --reverse -- "${FILES[@]}" | head -n1`
git format-patch --stdout "$FIRST_COMMIT"^..HEAD -- "${FILES[@]}"

# git-import-history
cd "$1"
git am
```

Since the scripts are named "git-*" and in my PATH, I use them like this:

```
git cp-history ../other-repo local/repo/file.txt
```

Comment: `FIRST_COMMIT=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000; git format-patch --stdout "$FIRST_COMMIT"^..HEAD -- config/deploy.rb` returns `fatal: bad revision '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000^..HEAD'`

Comment: @AlexTonkonozhenko Was the file added in the branch's first commit? We always add either an empty commit or an empty .gitignore file as the root to our repos to avoid special casing root commits. If the file was added in the root commit, you should be able to use `git format-patch --stdout --root HEAD -- "${FILES[@]}"` (untested, HEAD probably optional). Read `git help format-patch` for more details. The basic `git format-patch | (cd ; git am)` process should work, but you may have to fiddle with the details for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

## "Move" history

After `git filter-branch` has completed, the branches contain only the filtered history. You can now just push the branches to a different repository:

```
git init --bare ../elsewhere
git push ../elsewhere master branch1 branch2 branch3
```

Now you have a bare repository with the filtered history from which you can clone new repositories.

## Include some other file

If you are missing one file in the filtered history, you have to repeat the filtering so that it is not excluded.

Comment: So the issue is how to filter only that file using `filter-branch`

Comment: @Alex, this is a different question, then.